# Reading to text files correctly and feeding items to class objects

Tags: vb.net, file-io

A small task am doing requires me to read through a text file and put those items into an object which i add to an ArrayList. However, am finding it difficult to make the code work correctly. In the text file items are in groups of 5 separated by an empty line. My logic doesnt seem to work right and therefore I seek further help. Attached is a screenshot of the text file followed by my code

```
Public Class BrowseReservations
    Private objectStore As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Private Shared basePath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    Private Shared filePath As String = Path.Combine(basePath, "reservations.txt")

    Private Sub populateList()
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        objectStore.Clear()
        Dim rc As ReservationRecord = New ReservationRecord()
        Dim AllLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        For i As Integer = 0 To AllLines.Count() - 1
            If counter = 0 Then
                rc.setfullDate(AllLines(i))
            ElseIf counter = 1 Then
                rc.setmonthName(AllLines(i))
            ElseIf counter = 2 Then
                rc.sethoursChartered(Convert.ToInt32(AllLines(i)))
            ElseIf counter = 3 Then
                rc.setyatchName(AllLines(i))
            ElseIf counter = 4 Then
                rc.setyatchLength(Convert.ToInt32(AllLines(i)))
            ElseIf counter = 5 Then
                rc.settotalCost(AllLines(i))
                objectStore.Add(rc)
            ElseIf counter = 6 Then 'This is the empty space between groups
                counter = -1
            End If
            counter += 1
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's how the text file look like just incase the image doesnt appear.

04/09/2017 12:18:30
Apr
13
Catalina
22
$1235

04/09/2017 12:34:19
Apr
5
Hans Christin
30
$800

04/09/2017 12:34:33
Apr
38
Hobie
32
$7296

Instead of feeding each group correctly, only the last group is fed in the object. Some of the content is also lost eg Catalina (strings in the 4th item of each group). Kindly help

Comment: `Dim rc As ReservationRecord = New ReservationRecord()` - you need multiple instances of `ReservationRecord` to store all of them, so you know.

Comment: To extend on what I said, keep a `List(Of ReservationRecord)` and have a counter per group, so every time it hits the blank line, add the counter. Then on the first (0), create a new Record and add it to your list. Then continually modify it until 6.

Comment: And what could be causing loss of some information such as strings?

Comment: Does the information loss include the first group @AstroguyPasa?

Comment: Add this line 'rc = New ReservationRecord()' after the line that says 'objectStore.Add(rc)'.  All you're doing at the moment is continually overwriting the same record

Comment: To illustrate the previous comments.  you need to create a list before the do loop  dim mylist as new list(of ReservationRecord), add if counter = 0 then rc =  new ReservationRecord().  at if counter = 6 then mylist.add(rc)

Comment: He is.  he has objectstore which is there to hold an array of records, he adds to it when he gathered all the data items.  Putting the new in at counter=0 is a better idea than mine though.

Comment: I did the fix and the it worked great. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my and Haim Katz comments:

```
Public Class BrowseReservations
Private objectStore As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
Private Shared basePath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
Private Shared filePath As String = Path.Combine(basePath, "reservations.txt")

Private Sub populateList()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    objectStore.Clear()
    Dim rc As ReservationRecord
    Dim AllLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    For i As Integer = 0 To AllLines.Count() - 1
        If counter = 0 Then
            rc = New ReservationRecord()
            rc.setfullDate(AllLines(i))
        ElseIf counter = 1 Then
            rc.setmonthName(AllLines(i))
        ElseIf counter = 2 Then
            rc.sethoursChartered(Convert.ToInt32(AllLines(i)))
        ElseIf counter = 3 Then
            rc.setyatchName(AllLines(i))
        ElseIf counter = 4 Then
            rc.setyatchLength(Convert.ToInt32(AllLines(i)))
        ElseIf counter = 5 Then
            rc.settotalCost(AllLines(i))
            objectStore.Add(rc)
        ElseIf counter = 6 Then 'This is the empty space between groups
            counter = -1
        End If
        counter += 1
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```